# Off-topic doesn't tell you what you can ask?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, close-reasons, off-topic, help-center

On old Stack Overflow posts, we had close reasons:

[image: SO Old reason]

> Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming within the scope [defined by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope. Read more about reopening questions here.

Now, we have default close reasons. Default reasons are used when a site provides no custom reasons, or the custom reasons that have been selected are not the same among close voters.

[image: Open Source Close Reason]

> This question does not appear to relate to open source, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help).

Each reason is a "generic" close reason: the reason that appears when none of the reasons were chosen, or if the reasons conflicted. Either way, there is a big fundamental difference between the two, which is the link.

The old close reason links directly to the on-topic page, while the newer ones just link to the help center. Intuitively, linking to the on-topic page means that users find the correct page faster, and have no reason not to.

Shouldn't close reasons that mark posts as off-topic link directly to the on-topic page?

Comment: AFAIK the off-topic close reasons are managed on a per-site basis by the mods of that site... SE doesn't really control those reasons.

Comment: @Catija I'm talking about the default close reasons, not necessarily custom close reasons... But I think default close reasons still link to the help center, and not the on-topic page. Also, custom close reasons link to the help center, in the added sentence that is at the end. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: There is not a default "off topic" close reason... At least not on any of the sites I use...

Comment: @Catija The "default" reason is when two or more reasons are selected, or if there is no custom reasons to choose from.

Comment: Yep, that were mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the in-code off-topic close reasons do actually link to `/help/on-topic`. However, *sites* have their own close reasons; even the default close reason is site-specific. I've edited the default close reason for Open Source SE to use `/help/on-topic`, but I'm not really going to go through all the other sites to check. :-)